# Is there any relevance between Boolean Algebras and Fields?

Tags: logic, category-theory, set-theory, universal-algebra, forcing

In some sense Boolean Algebras and Fields have same operators and constants. In both structures there are operators addition ($+$ , $\vee$), multiplication ($\times$ , $\wedge$), inverse with respect to addition ($-$ , $\neg$), inverse with respect to multiplication ($^{-1}$ , $\neg$) and constant symbols $0$, $1$ but these algebraic structures obey different axioms and the rules of inverse and identity are not completely match because in Boolean algebras $\neg$ doesn't show the properties of an inverse operator. e.g.

$\neg$ is "not" an inverse for $\vee$ because $\forall x\in\mathbb{B}~~~x\vee \neg x =1\neq 0$.

$\neg$ is "not" an inverse for $\wedge$ because $\forall x\in\mathbb{B}~~~x\wedge \neg x =0\neq 1$.

But there are similarities between $\neg$ and $^{-1}$, $-$ because $\neg$ sends each "variable" object $x$ of a Boolean algebra to a "constant" object but it does this in an "inverse" way with respect to the fields. For example $x\vee\neg x$ "should" be $0$ (because there is a natural correspondence between $\vee$ and $+$) but is $1$ and $x\wedge\neg x$ "should" be $1$ (because there is a natural correspondence between $\wedge$ and $\times$) but is $0$. Perhaps we need to revise our intuition about the "naturality" of the correspondences $\vee\leftrightarrow +$ and $\wedge\leftrightarrow \times$.

**Question:** Is there a natural way to assign a field $\mathbb{F}=\langle F,+,\times,-,^{-1},0,1\rangle$ to a given Boolean algebra $\mathbb{B}=\langle B,\vee,\wedge,\neg,0,1\rangle$? (Perhaps we should show a Boolean algebra with two different negation symbols one for a $\vee$-inverse operator and another for $\wedge$ as follows $\mathbb{B}=\langle B,\vee,\wedge,\neg_{\vee}, \neg_{\wedge},0,1\rangle$)

What about assigning a natural Boolean algebra to a field? By a "natural" way I mean something like category morphisms and quotient constructions, etc. Please introduce references for partial results.

**Motivation:** Forcing could be interpreted as a Boolean valued ultraproduct of the universe of all sets $V$. I am asking about the possibility of defining forcing using the structure of field. Another motivation comes from a similarity between the notion of "extending universe using a generic object" and "extending a field using a transcendental object".

Comment: There is a functor isomorphism between the category of boolean algebras and the category of boolean rings (which are rings in which multiplication is idempotent).  This basically means that the objects correspond with each other and the morphisms between them also correspond.

For this reason, I don't think you'd be able to necessarily get it with fields, but rings are 'almost' fields.

Comment: There is no inverse for $\lor$. It has an identity element $0$ (false) but $x \lor \lnot x \neq 0$, so $\lnot$ is not an inverse for $x$ under $\lor$. Similarly for $\land$ and its neutral element $1$ (true).

Comment: The answer is strongly negative because Boolean algebras always define a partial order, whereas fields don't have to define any ordering.

Comment: I wrote this long answer why we shouldn't use this sort of analogy to describe forcing. But I think it fits a blog more than it fits an answer on MSE. I'll finish it up there and post a link if you are interest.

Comment: How do you define an inverse for $\lor$? Recall that $\lor$ is really just the union of two sets. If $A\cup B=C$, how do you remove $B$ from this operation? If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, sure just intersect with the complement of $B$, but if not then you bound to remove elements from $A$. And the operation cannot be defined by using $A$, since it has to be definable only from $B$ (otherwise it's really moot, for obvious reasons: it's dead easy to define $A$ from $A\cup B$ if both $A$ and $B$ are given).

Comment: "For example x∨¬x "should" be 0 (because there is a natural correspondence between ∨ and +) but is 1 and x∧¬x "should" be 1 (because there is a natural correspondence between ∧ and ×) but is 0. Perhaps we need to revise our intuition about the "naturality" of the correspondences ∨↔+ and ∧↔×."  I can see the correspondence between ∧ and ×.  However, ∨ doesn't correspond to + since V(1, 1)=1, while +(1, 1)=2.  More appropriate correspondences are ∧ and MIN (or infimum) and V and MAX (or supremum).

Answer (score 4):

The most natural algebraic object to associate with a Boolean algebra is a Boolean ring, in which the addition is the disjoint union $a\oplus b:= a\wedge \neg b\vee b\wedge\neg a$ and the multiplication is still $\vee$. Since $a\oplus a=0$ every Boolean ring is of characteristic $2$; the only Boolean ring that's a field is the field with two elements, since the only way $a\wedge b$ can be $1$ is if either $a$ or $b$ is.

It's possible to extend the notion of boolean-valued models to models valued in Heyting algebras, and further still; this hinges on the topological aspects of Boolean algebras more than the algebraic. Via related topos theoretic methods one can get Cohen's results in just a few pages, essentially by forcing but without using quite his terminology. On the other hand I think Asaf's objection indicates that you shouldn't expect a good notion of forcing with values in a field.

Comment: Where can one learn these topos theoretic methods? I don't have an algebraic geometry background FWIW.

Comment: In Maclane and Moerdijk, or in Johnstone for the deeper aspects. Nobody else who wrote on topos theory after Grothendieck has an algebraic geometry background either, don't worry!